# PIWIK get total page views

Tags: php, matomo

I'm writing a custom report for Piwik and I want to get the number of page views (as opposed to visits) for a site.

I can't find it in the api anywhere.  I do this currently

```
            $request = new Request('
                        module=API
                        &method=VisitsSummary.get
                        &idSite='.$siteid.'
                        &period=year
                        &date='.$dateResult.','.$monthis .'
                        &format=PHP
                        &filter_limit=200

                        &token_auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            ');

            $result = $request->process();
```

Which works and allows me to get the visits (and other info I need) but the page views aren't there.  Initially I though that the actions - nb_actions - would be the number but that shows a lot more that the reported number in Piwik.

Hopefully someone knows how to make this work

thanks